# Use specific status code error page in area | Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I manage status codes error using

> `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCodeError/{0}");`

But when an error occurs in the area, the page is redirected out of the area and shows the general error page.
How do I make sure that an area-specific error page is displayed if an error occurs in the area?

Comment: do you mean that you want the error page to be rooted from the corresponding area? e.g: you have an area named `customer`, if some error is raised in that area, the redirected error page should locate at `/customer/StatusCodeError/{0}`?

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extensibility point to modify the behavior of `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`, the `location` is formatted internally using `string.Format` and with only one argument passed in the placeholder `{0}` for the status code. So at the calling time (passing in the `location` format), we have no understanding about the `area` which is a route value available only in the context of a request processing. So you can refer to the source for `StatusCodePagesExtensions` and can see that  `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` just depends on an overload of the extension method `StatusCodePagesExtensions.UseStatusCodePages`, you can freely copy the code and modify it to make another version of `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` that accepts a `location` format which supports some arguments from the route values.
Here I've made a simple one for you:

```
public static class StatusCodePagesApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseStatusCodePagesWithRouteDataAndRedirects(this IApplicationBuilder app, string locationFormat)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        var shouldPrependPathBase = locationFormat.StartsWith("~");
        locationFormat = shouldPrependPathBase ? locationFormat.Substring(1) : locationFormat;

        return app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
        {
            //here is the point we can evaluate for the actual location
            //by replacing the placeholders with route value                
            var location = Regex.Replace(locationFormat, @"\{[^}]+\}", m => {
                //ignore the placeholder for status code
                if (m.Value == "{0}") return m.Value;
                var routeKey = m.Value.Trim('{', '}');                    
                var routeValue = context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue(routeKey);
                return routeValue?.ToString();
            });
            location = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, location, context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
            location = (shouldPrependPathBase ? context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase : PathString.Empty) + location;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(location);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can include any route data in the `location` format, in your case you just need the `area`, so the code will be like this:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRouteDataAndRedirects("/{area}/StatusCodeError/{0}");
```

**NOTE**: be careful with redirecting, you may encounter an error saying something like *too many redirects*, that's because of redirecting to a URL which in return causes a loop of redirects.